# ExtJS 4, Direct File upload in Chrome: Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, upload, submit, rpc

I try to upload a file in "**Google Chrome**", with "**ExtJS 4**" and **Direct form submit**.

On every Way I try in chrome, I get the Error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

In Firefox it works without exeptions.

I searched allready in different forums, but not a single problem with this failure, give me single idea what I can use for my task.

Can somebody try to help me?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.DirectUpload', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

itemId: 'DirectUpload',
title: 'Direct Upload',

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    me.initialConfig = Ext.apply({
        paramOrder: [
            'name',
            'file'
        ]
    }, me.initialConfig);

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        paramOrder: [
            'name',
            'file'
        ],
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                itemId: 'name',
                fieldLabel: 'Label',
                name: 'name'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'filefield',
                id: 'file',
                itemId: 'file',
                fieldLabel: 'Label',
                name: 'file'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                handler: function(button, event) {
                    this.up('form').getForm().submit({
                        scope: this,
                        success: function(form, action)
                        {
                            console.log(action);
                        },
                        failure: function(form, action)
                        {
                            console.log(action);
                        }

                    });
                },
                text: 'MyButton'
            }
        ]
    });

    me.processDirectUploadTest(me);
    me.callParent(arguments);
},

processDirectUploadTest: function(config) {
    config.api = {submit: 'RPC.fileupload.filterUploads'};
    return config;
}
```

});

Comment: What Ext JS version are you using?

Comment: I use ExtJS 4.2.1. 
And Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m, fyi.

Comment: Okay, now I get the error "TypeError: cyclic object value" in Firefox :(